# Spring MVC : Storing secret key in database or session for encryption/decryption

Tags: java, spring, encryption, spring-security, cryptography

- I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am using
  Spring-security for authentication. Now, there is a Person class with
  username and password and I am saving the password currently by
  encrypting it with BCrypt.

  - Now my problem is I would like to encrypt & decrypt 2 columns in the
    database on the fly. So with some help, I was able to successfully
    get the plainText password.
  - I would like to know how can I generate a key from this plaintext
    password, and is it a good idea to save this key in the database so I
    can directly access it for encrypting and decrypting those 2 columns.

This is what I have till now :

```
byte[] encodedKey     = Base64.decode(stringKey, Base64.DEFAULT);
SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey, 0, encodedKey.length, "AES");
```

Should I store the encoded key in database and use it? Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: bcrypt is a hashing algorithm and you say you have successfully "decrypted" it "on the fly". I would like to see how that is possible, because you just broke bcrypt. (It is unclear how your AES encryption relates to bcrypt hashing.)

Comment: @ArtjomB. : I didn't break Bcrypt, if I would I wouldn't be asking such naive questions here...lol.. I was able to retrieve it before Spring-security deletes it.

Comment: Also the reason I would like to use some other algo than Bcrypt is so everytime I use Bcrypt the plain password, I get different output, spring security manages to compare when the bean in injected. But I really don't know if I should use it as key.